# Rails, confirm password on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm using the railscasts authentication http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch authorization. How can the edit user profile check password before saving the changes?

Full source code: https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to authenticate using the password entered on the before saving any changes. Similar to what Ryan has for create:

if User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  # save changes

Comment: Yes that works, though it has some limitations, e.g. it gets more complicated if the password itself can be changed in the edit form, or if the email can be changed or is not even part of the form.

Answer (score 2):

What Devise does and is probably the best idea is to write an `update_with_password` method in your user model which is called in the `update` action of your `users_controller`. This method uses `update_attributes` to edit the user model, but only if the current password is specified correctly.

I recommend looking at the Devise source (and other gems) if you'd like to learn more about building your own authentication.